# Content-Disposition with 302 redirect

Tags: php, http, redirect, header, content-disposition

This was working last night, but I must have accidentally changed something, because it isn't now.

What I am trying to do should be clear from these headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=english_customizable.xml
Location: http://tortoisewrath.com/files/2.xml
```

However, when this header is sent, the `Content-Disposition` part doesn't work after the redirect.

...Why?

Comment: Those two headers need to be on separate lines, is that a posting mistake or genuine?

Comment: @sg3s Sorry for the late reply; I was testing that. I didn't know that they needed to be on separate lines; however, I can't figure out how to make them be on separate lines in PHP. I'll work on that...

Comment: Well, I got that to work, but the Content-Disposition doesn't work now. I've updated my question with the new problem.

Comment: Actually, it’s not entirely clear for me what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is inadvisable check this question; [Header Location + Content Disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458854/header-location-content-disposition)

**Content-Disposition + Location header**

But you can do it, to make it work you will have to buffer your whole response before sending it. You can do this with output buffering

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Else the browser may interpret the `Location` header before the file is downloaded. It's sketchy either way, so you shouldn't want to do this.

**Please note** that forcing 'save as' using `Content-Disposition: attachment;` will make sure the client doesn't go/navigate anywhere, so the method below on its own should be fine in any case.

**Streaming a file in php**

To just quote [a guy who has his brains in the right place](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#107581):

```
// To use header() with 'content-type', why don't you use mime_content_type() function rather than checking the type on the basis of extension? 
// Example code: 

<?php 
$file="test.docx"; 
header("Pragma: public"); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file); 
header("Content-type: ".mime_content_type($file)); 
header('Content-Encoding: identity'); 
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
readfile($file); 
?> 

// Use $file to map to whichever type of file. 
// Note: the mime types should already be defined in apache settings
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#107581

Note that the original answer used `Content-Transfer-Encoding` which doesn't actually exist in HTTP. The comment below that source explains it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#107044

Comment: I hereby 302 you to the asker's comment on the accepted answer for that question: How will that go with ~ 300mb movie files :\?

Comment: @Tortoise well, it won't, probably. That's my point about it being sketchy. And that is probably why it doesn't work 'anymore'.

Comment: Is there any means by which to call a `Content-Disposition: attachment` or equivalent on a file without buffering it? (As stated in the question, I'm pretty sure this was working in one way or another yesterday...)

Comment: @Tortoise yes, first make sure output buffering is **disabled** then you can just `echo file_get_contents(/* file path here */)` and it should stream the file directly to the client. This does mean you can't use the `Location` header though.

Comment: The `Location` header wasn't entirely necessary; the necessary part was streaming the file to the client. I'll let you know how well this works.

Comment: @Tortoise I updated my answer based on that question, since I found a method someone had thought about for more than two seconds.

Comment: YES YES YES YES YES YES YES YES THANK YOU (By the way, I thought about that for a full _three_ seconds, thank you very much.)

Comment: There is no Content-Transfer-Encoding header field in HTTP.

Comment: @JulianReschke I know, my bad for blindly copying an answer from somewhere else, fixed :)